# How to pass async variable in template (action) function?

Tags: asynchronous, angular, ionic2

I need to pass async variable to the function.
Something like this:

```xml
<div class="team" (click)="addToFavorite((match | async)?.id)">
```

And of course I have an error.

> Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression.

Maybe there is a way to transform async variable in JavaScript?

Comment: Would be kind if you'd let us know what the error is.

Comment: Worth a try

    `(click)="match.then(val => addToFavorite(val?.id))"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 
``` 
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression.
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
Thanks for quick reply!
It didnt work. 
`polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token > `

Comment: Then you probable need to define a helper method

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another option for simple variables and without any observables is writing value of the variable into hidden input:

```xml
<div *ngIf="(match | async)?.id">
    <input  #myControl [value]="(match | async).id" type="hidden" />
    <div class="team" (click)="addToFavorite(myControl.value)">
</div>
```

Comment: Very good workaround! However, I could only get this working, without the *ngIf wrapper around the input and button.

Comment: Awesome! Could be the sollution

Comment: This approach isn't working with boolean values, because *ngIf won't work with false

Answer (score 39):

Here is how I solved it :

```xml
<div *ngIf="(match | async) as match" class="team" (click)="addToFavorite(match.id)">
```

It's short, simple and it works.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(match | async) as match">
   <div class="team" (click)="addToFavorite(match.id)">
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Update January 20th 2021**

To be more clear I would name match observable source as match$.

And we can now use the new @ngrx/component package and use the new ngrxLet structural directive :

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="match$ as match">
  <div class="team" (click)="addToFavorite(match.id)">
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

The async pipe is no more necessary.
More info on ngrx.io, on this [link](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let).

Comment: I like this answer as it all template-driven

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to use a helper method:

```xml
<div class="team" (click)="onClick(match)">
```

```typescript
class MyComponent {
  onClick(event) {
    event.then(val => this.addToFavorite(val?.id);
  }
  addToFavorite(val) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this `val?.id` so I just pass value
and I still get observable in the addToFavorite() not a value itself

Comment: Why can't you use `val?.id`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `?` operator is only available inside angular 2 templates, and not inside Typescript component code. This feature hasn't been implemented yet for Typescript, but It seems to be in the works: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

Comment: @DevonSams thanks. I'm so used to it from Dart, I missed that it's not yet in TS. You are right, currently it is only available in template bindings.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```xml
<div class="team" (click)="addToFavorite(match)">
```

and then in your code:

```typescript
addToFavorite(obs: Observable<any>) {
  obs.take(1).subscribe(value => {
    addToFavoriteById(value.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have console error 
` inline template:12:38 caused by: obs.take is not a function`

Comment: You need to import operators like `.take()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in template.

But you can:

```xml
<div class="team" (click)="addToFavorite()">
```

and in your `.component.ts`:

```typescript
public addToFavorite() {
  this
    .match  // should retain last value (e.g. use BehaviorSubject)
    .first() // completes after passing one value only
    .subscribe(
      (matchValue) => {
        // your logic here
    });
}
```

Note: We are subscribing (and immediately unsubscribing), similarly `async` pipe subscribes to `Observable`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!