# Reactive Styled Templates with Parameterised Async Pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ngrx

I would like to change my code towards a Reactive style, however I am struggling with the syntax when attempting to pass through parameters within the async pipe to an `Observable`.

My current working code that is not Reactive (`stydent.component.ts)`:

```
deleteStudent(id: number) {
  this.uniCrudService.deleteStudent(id)
  .subscribe( res => {
    console.log(`deleteStudent: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
    this.getStudents();
  });
}
```

In my `student.component.html` template I am calling the `deleteStudent` like:

```
<a routerLink="" (click)="deleteStudent(student.id)">Delete</a>
```

The problem is that I need to use the `async` pipe on an observable function that receives a parameter (for a Reactive style?).

For example:

```
deleteStudent(id: number): Observable<Student> {
return this.deleteStudent$ = this.uniCrudService.deleteStudent(id)
  .pipe( tap (res => {
    console.log(`deleteStudent: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
    this.getStudents();
  }));
```

and in the template:

```
<a routerLink="" (click)="deleteStudent(student.id) | async">Delete</a>
```

However this throws the error: `Cannot have a pipe in an action expression`. Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300115/how-to-pass-async-variable-in-template-action-function) I am understanding that I cannot make this piece of my code Reactive, and I will be forced to keep the unwanted `subscription`. Is this the case? How do I make my `deleteStudent` Reactive and get rid of the `subscription`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a design issue there. The `deleteStudent(id: number)` is an event handler, so it should not return any values or have any subscribers. Your initial code is correct.

If you want a more "reactive" approach you could create a `Subject`:

```
public students$: Subject<any>;

constructor(){ 
   this.students$ = new Subject<any>();
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.students$.subscribe(() => { 
      // do something with students
   });
}

deleteStudent(id: number) {
 this.uniCrudService.deleteStudent(id)
 .subscribe( res => {
   console.log(`deleteStudent: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
   this.students$.next();
 });
```